# when I created a children object then how to get the parent's object

Tags: java

I know when I created the `Children` object,the same time ,a `Parent` object will be created ,is there any way to get the `Parent` object

```java
public class Parent {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Parent(){
        System.out.println(this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Children c = new Children();
    }
}

class Children extends Parent{

    private String toy;

    public Children(){
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: oh my god,my teacher tell me, no parent no son, It's big fault

Comment: @liuzhijun just to make it clear, even before the child is created, its (child's) constructor calls `super()` which is the parent constructor so in that way your teacher was right :P (refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) for more details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know when I created the Children object,the same time ,a Parent
>   object will be created ,is there any way to get the Parent object

Only a child object is created, which has attributes from both the parent and child itself.